# Gitlab's autodevops: Herokuish buildpack test can't find chrome binary

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab's "autodevops" feature comes with a default step in the 'test' stage called 'test', which uses herokuish to run my rails app's rspec suite. Unfortunately, it fails on my system/integration specs that requires the chrome browser to be installed.

I've tried adding `herokuish buildpack install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome` before `herokuish buildpack test` but it still can't find the Chrome binary. The error looks like the following:

```sh
Failure/Error:

visit root_path

  Webdrivers::VersionError:
    Failed to find Chrome binary or its version.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bit too late but here's a working solution as of September 2020.

https://github.com/guzmanoj/herokuish-install-chrome

The script will resolve the chrome dependencies so that CHROME_BIN will be defined in the host OS.